# how to access usb port of client pc from web app

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, fingerprint

I have a web app. now I want to add "present and absent by finger print" to this. everything work fine in localhost (add finger,remove finger and etc). I send device port name to functions to do jobs. 
but after publishing project I recognized that it can not find port in client's pc. 
now I want to now how can I access specific port in client's pc after publishing web app?
PS:if you need to know part of code just say it to show you, thank you

Comment: On localhost the server and the client side are the same. But when you deploy to a server the web application runs on another machine where you might not have permission. Question is the port access codes - are those server side or client side codes?

Comment: codes are in server side

Comment: That explains why it is not working. Do you have physical access to the server? Is the scanner attached to the Server or your local host PC?

Comment: scanner attached to local host pc

Comment: In that case you will need jquery/javascript based solution. Look into this: https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-connect-a-biometric-fingerprint-scanner-with-any-application-using-JavaScript

Comment: i had search but apparently the scanner device model which we use doesnt support javascript contoroling. if you know any solution please let me know, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Browsers don't let you to do it on purpose. However, you can create ActiveX objects, plugins or browser extensions to do it.
For example you can check [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/spano/archive/2007/09/19/hosting-a-windows-form-control-in-a-web-page.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I have understand the best way is windows application, so I did my job by creating c# windows application and did my job as well as I wanted.